# MP3 player for a website that will work on both web browsers and smartphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mp3

I have a Flash MP3 player for a website that works on web browsers and Android but doesn't work on iPhones or Windows Phone. I know it's because iPhones don't support Flash and I presume that's also the reason it doesn't work on Windows Phone.

I can't just a HTML 5 MP3 players as that won't work on older browsers (and might not work on Android?). So do I need to use two separate players and decide which one to use based on the user's browser or is there a better solution such as a plugin that handles all this for me?

Basically, are there any MP3 player solutions that will handle both web browsers (version 7+ for IE) and smartphones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: This is a html5 player, but has a Flash fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also drop in a link for the iphone that will use the native player (Something along the lines of 'iphone users click here' underneath your mp3 player) if you're trying to play a single file. It's quick and dirty but it does the job. There's more information here: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/iphoneaudio.html

That being said, I do like user1285360's answer quite a bit if you can implement it.